# Dereferencing 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to understand how 2D arrays are created in memory and I can not explain this weird behavior of pointers.

The following code:

```
int arr[4][3]={
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9},
    {10,11,12}
};

int main(){
    cout<<"&arr = "<<&arr<<endl;
    cout<<" arr = "<<arr<<endl;
    cout<<"*arr = "<<*arr<<endl;
    cout<<"*(int*)arr = "<<*(int*)arr<<endl;
}
```

produces the output:

```
&arr = 0x8049bc0
arr = 0x8049bc0
*arr = 0x8049bc0
*(int*)arr = 1
```

Code: http://ideone.com/CzeVMu

`arr` is "[an array of arrays that decays into a pointer to an array](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html)" and `*arr` (which is equivalent to `arr[0]`) is an array.

Since the values of `arr` and `*arr` are the same, it means that the memory location that `arr` points to is storing it's own address. But the memory location is actually storing the first element of the 2D array, which can be retrieved by first typecasting arr into `int*` like this:`*(int*)arr`. How is this possible?

Comment: "Since the values of `arr` and `*arr` are the same" - Huh? Check the types!

Comment: @Olaf, what do you mean?

Comment: In C a value always also has a type.They have different types, thus they are **not** the same! (Note: the dup question itself does not show a 2D array; see the accepted answer)

Comment: An array can decay into a pointer but it is not a pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I would really appreciate it if this question is unmarked as duplicate and someone can tell me how `*(int*)arr` and `*arr` give two different answers.

Comment: @HassanNadeem: I already gave you a reason. Anyway, see [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Just having external links is against site-rules.